# How to find out all missing time slot(s) on a day

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time

Is there any algorithms to find out all missing time slots on a day.

Given that there are four time slots which are selected.

**e.g. Expected input: 08:00-1259, 13:45-17:15, 14:15-19:00, 20:00-23:33**

I would like to find out all missing time slots based on the four time slots being selected **with below criteria**.

1. The selected time slots can be overlapped (e.g. 13:45-17:15, 14:15-19:59)
2. Ignore the missing time slot which is later than the end time of last time slot (e.g. don't show all missing time slot after 23:33)

**Expected output: 13:00-13:44, 19:01-19:59**

Feel free to try even if there are some similiar algorithms which are not meet above criteria.

**Update:**

I think it is not efficient enough for my trial.

I try to omit all ":" and loop over from 0 to 2359 and check if each minute is within ranges of four selected time slots or not. Once I found out a minute which is out of any selected time slots. That minute will be recorded as a start time of the missing time slot. Then, when the next minute which is within those four time slots is found. I will minus that minute with 1 and record it as the end time of a missing time slot.

e.g. when the counter at 1300, 1300 will be regarded as the start time of the missing time slot, and when the counter locates at 1345. I will minus one minute and mark the end time as 1344.

Comment: Please show us what have you tried till now?

Comment: Updated. As sisanared says, it is quite challenging to me. So, I want to know if there is any more efficient algorithms to compute the result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Sort the input by the start times (your example has them already sorted).
2. For each input time range except the last:

   - If the end time (plus one minute) is earlier than the next start time, record a gap.

Answer (score 2):

Efficiency depends on in what form your data is available. I can think of following way if data is stored in an array, sorted with start time, with even index as start and odd index as stop time of slot.

```
start          End

[0]0100      [1]0500

[2]0200      [3]0300  //case of slot totally covered by any previous slot

[4]0400      [5]0900  //case of slot partially covered by any previous slot 

[6]1200      [7]1500  //case of slot never covered

*** Notation [x]YYYY : x is array index and YYYY is time
```

```
1. MAX = element[0]
2. Loop for all index i
3. ----If element[i] > MAX 
4. --------If i is odd, MAX=element[i]
5. --------Else MAX to element[i] is missing slot
```

Comment: Voted. It is also a correct answer. I think it is so awesome, but John Zwinck comes first. So, I give a tick to him.

Comment: note that this algorithm also need to sort by start time first